# Pick a function to return from a function

Tags: python, function, return

I have a list of formulas which I like to use them inside a single function and only return if certain conditions are met for example:

```
def func(x,i):
    equation1=...
    equation2=equation1+...
    equation3=equation2+...
    return equationi
```

I'm wondering if there is any way of returning a specific function like above where `i` is a variable.

In general I would like to ask a wired question, how one can convert strings to line texts which can be used in python code. I mean if I have 'return','func' and i(as intiger) then how I can create return funci to be used as code in python script!

(I would also appreciate if anyone has a better question title to suggest!)

Comment: Put the functions in a dictionary, with the numbers as keys. Then return thatdict[i]. Don't try to generate variable names, that's mixing code and data.

Comment: If `func1` is a function, what is `func1 + ...` supposed to be?

Comment: @chepner, they were supposed to be equations, I just made it corect in question.

Comment: So, they are just strings?

Comment: @chepner, they are actual equations i.e equation1=a+b*x...  but I wanted to find a way to return this equations based on indication number i. I was ingeneral wondering how one can create line codes from strings which I got the answer, didn't try it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one way

```
return locals()['func' + str(i)]
```

Now that you know that, **don't do it**. Put the functions in a dict.

Comment: Don't handle implicitly what you can handle explicitly.

Comment: @chepner: meaning??

Comment: Meaning, delete everything except the last sentence of this answer (then flesh *that* out, instead of emphasizing the wrong approach so much).

Comment: @chepner: I made it clear it's not a good approach. Still, using `locals()` can be useful in some metaprogramming cases, so it doesn't hurt to know it exists.

Comment: Yes, it does, if you are led to believe it's a viable solution to a problem like this.

Comment: thanks "blue_note" it was great hint, I would avoid it as you mentioned. Dict is indeed a good idea but I haven't tought about it myself. Thanks @chepner for his serious warning as well.